# Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

UserBean.java

```
   package com.school.bean;

   public class UserBean
   {
private Integer uid;
private String uname;   
private String password;
private String email;


public Integer getUid() {
    return uid;
}
public void setUid(Integer uid) {
    this.uid = uid;
}
public String getUname() {
    return uname;
}
public void setUname(String uname) {
    this.uname = uname;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
    }
```

UserController.java
i am not sure with the use of @ModelAttribute
I am using it to accept input from user.

```
    package com.school.controller;

     import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

    import com.school.bean.UserBean;
    import com.school.model.User;
    import com.school.service.UserService;

    import com.school.model.UserRole;
    import com.school.service.UserRoleService;
    import com.school.bean.UserRoleBean;



    @Controller
     public class UserController {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;
     private UserRoleService userRService;
int urole=0;

@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView saveUser(@ModelAttribute("user") UserBean      userBean,BindingResult result)
{
    User user = prepareModel(userBean);
    userService.addUser(user);
  saveUserRole(user);
    return new ModelAndView("index");
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView welcome() {
    System.out.println("signup!!!\n/n");
    return new ModelAndView("index");
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/add")
public ModelAndView signup()
{
    urole=2;    //for normal user
    System.out.println("signup!!!\n/n");
    return new ModelAndView("addUser");
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/member")
public ModelAndView becomeMember()
{
    urole=1;        //for school admin
    return new ModelAndView("addUser");
}
private User prepareModel(UserBean userBean){
    User user = new User();
    user.setUserId(userBean.getUid());
    user.setUserPassword(userBean.getPassword());
    user.setUserEmail(userBean.getEmail());
    userBean.setUid(null);
    return user;
}   
    }
```

UserDaoImpl.java (i am avoiding the UserDao Interface)
         package com.school.dao;

```
      import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
      import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
      import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

      import com.school.model.User;

      @Repository("userDao")
      public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void addUser(User user) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(user);
}

public User getUser(String uName){
    return (User) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(User.class,uName);
}
    }
```

User.java
        package com.school.model;

```
     import java.io.Serializable;

     import javax.persistence.Column;
     import javax.persistence.Entity;
     import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
     import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
      import javax.persistence.Id;
     import javax.persistence.Table;



    @Entity
    @Table(name="User")
    public class User implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -723583058586873479L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "userid")
private Integer userId;

@Column(name="username")
private String username;


@Column(name="userpassword")
private String userPassword;

@Column(name="useremail")
private String userEmail;

public Integer getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(Integer userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getUserPassword() {
    return userPassword;
}

public void setUserPassword(String userPassword) {
    this.userPassword = userPassword;
}


public String getUserEmail() {
    return userEmail;
}

public void setUserEmail(String userEmail) {
    this.userEmail = userEmail;
}
  }
```

UserServiceImpl.java(Again avoiding interface UserService
        package com.school.service;

```
     import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

     import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
     import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
     import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

     import com.school.dao.UserDao;
     import com.school.model.User;

     @Service("userService")
     @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS, readOnly = true)
     public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

@Autowired
private UserDao userDao;

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
public void addUser(User user) {
    userDao.addUser(user);
}
 public User checkUser(String uName)
 {
     return (userDao.getUser(uName));
 }

    }
```

addUser.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
   <html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>School Review System SignUp</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form:form method="POST" action="/AuthorizationAndAuthentication/save.html">

    <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label >USERID</label></td>
                <td><input value="${user.uid}" readonly="true" ></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><label>USERNAME</label></td>
                <td><input  value="${user.uname}"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><label>PASSWORD</label></td>
                <td><input value="${user.password}"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><label>EMAIL</label></td>
                <td><input value="${user.email}"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
          </tr>
        </table> 
    </form:form>

</body>
```

sdnext-servlet.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:resources/database.properties"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.school.controller com.school.dao com.school.service"/>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager"/>

<bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DAVDB" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.school.model.User</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />


</bean>
```

Comment: What is your table design? Did you create the table by hand? Or hibernate generated it? You create it without making autoincrement and hibernate still works with it, but you get this kind of issues.

Comment: this is how i created the table

CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `userid` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userpassword` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `username` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `useremail` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userid`)
);

Comment: how to resolve this issues

Answer (score 0):

Your persistence provider is not able to determine which strategy should use for ID generation. It depens on db used as well, as some db dosn't suport sequence or identity.

try to specify concrete id generation strategypersistence provider.

```
strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY

//not for mysql
strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE
```

or set up proper hibernate.dialect  in your config

```
    <bean id="SessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
     <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: i am using mysql as my database.

Comment: I am new to hibernate,what is a persistence provider and how can i set up hibernate.dialect?

Comment: its giving the same error with identity and sequence.

Comment: is there something wrong with the way i am taking input

Comment: It depens on how is your project configured.  But there is sessionFactory in your dao so I quesit like this

Comment: have a look at sdnext-servlet.xml